# How to save flappy bird (made with pygame on python 3.9) scores into sql database

Tags: python, sql, database, pygame

I m new to pygame and started learning it by making flappy bird by watching tutorials. I need to save the player's name and score to the sql database ( the table already has been created by me to store data) for a project. But whenever the program comes to saving the name and score, the GUI gets hanged rather than restarting the game and the data doesn't get saved. Here's the code:-

```
import pygame, sys, random
def sql():
    import mysql.connector as c
    m=c.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password= "password",database="flappy 
bird")
    my=m.cursor()
    n=input('enter your name')
    r = score
    my.execute("insert into table(name, score) values({},'{}')".format(n,r))
    m.commit()
    my.execute("select * from table")
    for i in my:
      print(i)

def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos,900))
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos + 576,900))

def create_pipe():
    random_pipe_pos = random.choice(pipe_height)
    bottom_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (700,random_pipe_pos))
    top_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midbottom = (700,random_pipe_pos - 300))
    return bottom_pipe,top_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.centerx -= 5
    visible_pipes = [pipe for pipe in pipes if pipe.right > -50]
    return visible_pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.bottom >= 1024:
            screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)
        else:
            flip_pipe = pygame.transform.flip(pipe_surface,False,True)
            screen.blit(flip_pipe,pipe)

def check_collision(pipes):
    global can_score
    for pipe in pipes:
        if bird_rect.colliderect(pipe):
            death_sound.play()
            can_score = True
            return False

    if bird_rect.top <= -100 or bird_rect.bottom >= 900:
        can_score = True
        return False

    return True

def rotate_bird(bird):
    new_bird = pygame.transform.rotozoom(bird,-bird_movement * 3,1)
    return new_bird

def bird_animation():
    new_bird = bird_frames[bird_index]
    new_bird_rect = new_bird.get_rect(center = (100,bird_rect.centery))
    return new_bird,new_bird_rect

def score_display(game_state):
    if game_state == 'main_game':
        score_surface = game_font.render(str(int(score)),True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)
    if game_state == 'game_over':
        score_surface = game_font.render(f'Score: {int(score)}' ,True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)

        high_score_surface = game_font.render(f'High score: {int(high_score)}',True, 
        (255,255,255))
        high_score_rect = high_score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,850))
        screen.blit(high_score_surface,high_score_rect)

def update_score(score, high_score):
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    return high_score

def pipe_score_check():
    global score, can_score 

    if pipe_list:
        for pipe in pipe_list:
            if 95 < pipe.centerx < 105 and can_score:
                score += 1
                score_sound.play()
                can_score = False
            if pipe.centerx < 0:
                can_score = True

#pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency = 44100, size = 16, channels = 2, buffer = 1024)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_font = pygame.font.Font('04B_19.ttf',40)

# Game Variables
gravity = 0.5
bird_movement = 0
game_active = True
score = 0
high_score = 0
can_score = True
bg_surface = 
pygame.image.load('assets/background- 
day.png').convert()
bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bg_surface)

floor_surface = 
pygame.image.load('assets/base.png').convert()
floor_surface = 
pygame.transform.scale2x(floor_surface)
floor_x_pos = 0

bird_downflap = 
pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/bluebird- 
downflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_midflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/bluebird- 
midflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_upflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/bluebird- 
upflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_frames = [bird_downflap,bird_midflap,bird_upflap]
bird_index = 0
bird_surface = bird_frames[bird_index]
bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

BIRDFLAP = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(BIRDFLAP,200)

# bird_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/bluebird-midflap.png').convert_alpha()
# bird_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bird_surface)
# bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

pipe_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/pipe-green.png')
pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pipe_surface)
pipe_list = []
SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1200)
pipe_height = [400,600,800]

game_over_surface = 
pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/message.png').convert_alpha())
game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect(center = (288,512))

flap_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_wing.wav')
death_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_hit.wav')
score_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_point.wav')
score_sound_countdown = 100
SCOREEVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
pygame.time.set_timer(SCOREEVENT,100)

while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()
       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active:
               bird_movement = 0
               bird_movement -= 12
               flap_sound.play()
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active == False:
               game_active = True
               pipe_list.clear()
               bird_rect.center = (100,512)
               bird_movement = 0
               score = 0

       if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
           pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())

       if event.type == BIRDFLAP:
           if bird_index < 2:
               bird_index += 1
           else:
               bird_index = 0

           bird_surface,bird_rect = bird_animation()

   screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))

   if game_active:
       # Bird
       bird_movement += gravity
       rotated_bird = rotate_bird(bird_surface)
       bird_rect.centery += bird_movement
       screen.blit(rotated_bird,bird_rect)
       game_active = check_collision(pipe_list)

       # Pipes
       pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
       draw_pipes(pipe_list)
    
       # Score
       pipe_score_check()
       score_display('main_game')
   else:
       screen.blit(game_over_surface,game_over_rect)
       high_score = update_score(score,high_score)
       score_display('game_over')
       sql()
    


   # Floor
   floor_x_pos -= 1
   draw_floor()
   if floor_x_pos <= -576:
       floor_x_pos = 0


   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(120)
```

please tell how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: did you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if it display any error? You can also use `print()` in many places to see which line of code is executed when it hangs? If it needs longer time to save it then it is normal that it hangs - it can't save and update GUI at the same time. You would have to run one of this jobs in seprated thread. And maybe instead of using database you should use something simpler - like files JSON, CSV or `pickle`

Comment: if you use `input()` then it is not strange that it hangs - it can't wait for `input` and run main event loop at the same time. And when event loop doesn't runs then it looks like it hangs

Comment: It doesn't show any errors on cmd or any other editor(i use visual studio code). The output just keeps on asking to input the name without restarting the game. The GUI on the first loop is running perfectly, only the storing data part is causing the problem. It's mandatory to use  MySQL database for the project. What should I do to resolve it? Should I make a module for the sql part and import it in the main module?  I tried creating a reset() function which covered the whole code and called it under sql() to restart the game but it's not working either.

Comment: you should have function which sets default values in all variables at start - and when finish game then you should run this function again to reset all values to default values. You should rather execute it after `sql()`, not inside `sql()`

Comment: I put all the game variables under a start() func  and called both start() and reset() after sql() (first start() and then reset()) . It’s still showing the same problem. I tried calling pygame.quit() and sys.exit() after sql() (without start() and reset())  and it’s saving the data now. But  the game can’t restart if i  put them there.

Comment: as for me `start()` and `reset()` should do the same so you need only one of them - I would keep `reset()`. And you have to remeber that inside function you have to use `global` to change value in external variables. If you don't use `global` then you create local varaibles inside function and it doesn't change values in external varaibles. And don't waste time on `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit() ` - in other programs you don't exit them to use new values - you don't exit web browser to load new page.

Comment: I reduced your code (use one image for all objects, remove fonts and sounds) and I could run it. After `sql()` you have to set at least `game_active = True` and it restarts. later you may need other (re)sets - like reset points

Comment: can u please attach ur code? I m confused with the reset points. Thank you for taking ur time and helping me!

Comment: in my code I added only `game_active = True` directly after `sql()` - nothing more.

Comment: ok! should I make the game variables global too under the reset ()? I have done that with score and can_score inside other function. ( pipe_score_check()) so that i can use the final value in my database.

Comment: I used `game_active = True` directlu after `sql()` without using `reset()` I didn't have use global. But if you use `game_active = True` inside `reset()` then you have to use also `global game_active`. If you don't do this then it will create local variable `game_active` inside function and it will not change value in external/global variable `game_active`. For every variable used in `reset()` you will have ti use `global`

Comment: it is still not running properly... I opened my database and the table was empty. The GUI quickly restarts without giving a chance to press space bar to play again and produces the dead sound music after it. (all this happens in like a sec)

Comment: if you want to wait for space bar press then you will have to use more states - `game_active`, `saving`, `wait_for_space`, etc. and execute different code for different state. `if game_active: ... elif saving: ... elif `wait_for_space` . In current code after saving in sql you doen't change state so it repate `sql`. And when I use `game_active = True` after `sql()` then it goes back directy to game without waitng for spacebar. After `sql()` you will have to use `wait_for_space = True`. And when you press spacebar then set `game_active = True` and reset `wait_for_space = False`

Comment: if you mean to wait until you press spacebar then you have to use another state - `wait_for_space`. And use it to skip `sql()`.

Comment: and what should i put under saving if sql() would be called under else:

Comment: when I run it with game_active = True after sql() , the bird kept crashing into the pipe instead of restarting automatically from the beginning and the idle kept asking to input name after each crash.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have pointed out, calling `input()` will block your program from processing events, so the operating system will think your program has frozen.

To achieve your goals with minimal redesign, you can incorporate the built-in tkinter dialogs to obtain a user name instead of using `input()`. The application will still block, but your operating system won't think it is non-responsive.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog

def prompt_username():
    """Create a Tk file dialog and cleanup when finished"""
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.withdraw()  # hide window
    user_name = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring(
        "Name?", "What is your name?", parent=top
    )
    top.destroy()
    return user_name
```

In your `sql()` function, replace `n=input('enter your name')` with `n = prompt_username()`. Although you could do yourself a favour and use variable names with more than one character.

You'll see a dialog like this:

[image: Username dialog]

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html) for more information.